# How to give a fixed size to fontawesome icons

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a footer and used fontawesome icons with border.
On the following code I display the items and intend to have them as the picture shows

[image]

I was nearly there until I found that when I resize the screen, the icons also shrink like the photo show

Here my styling:

```
$footer: #464646;

.footer-font-awesome{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-indent: 0;  
}
footer#colophon{
    background-color: $footer;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 40px;

     ul,li,p{
      margin: 0;
    }

    .site-info{
        .textwidget {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

            div.box{
                display: flex;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 25%;
                align-items: center;
                p{
                    padding-left:8px;
                }
            }
            .email,
            .phone,
            .address{
                padding-right: 40px;
            }

            .email{
                &:before{
                    @extend .footer-font-awesome;  
                    content: '\f003';
                }
            }

            .phone{
                &:before{
                    @extend .footer-font-awesome;  
                    content: '\f095';
                }
            }

            .back-top{
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .address{
                &:before{
                    @extend .footer-font-awesome;  
                    content: '\f041';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my html structure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="site-info">
    <section id="black-studio-tinymce-33" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="box email">
          <p>Email<br> <span class="unbold"><a>info@web2web.co.za</a></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box phone">
          <p>Phone<br> <span class="unbold">021 823 8384</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box address">
          <p>Address<br> <span class="unbold">Century City, Cape Town</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box back-top">
          <p><span class="unbold"><a class="back-top">To the top</a></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>              
  </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer>
```

[image]

How can I style my icons as the first pictures shows with no problem even when I resize?

[Hope you can edit from my snippet](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/dOjPgM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just set `min-width` on `.footer-font-awesome`

```
.footer-font-awesome{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    min-width: 40px; // This...
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-indent: 0;  
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, why does setting 'min-width' fix the problem since the pseudo-element is given a specific width in the first place?

Comment: Marc Audet, When you simply set a width, that setting will be subject to change when adjust the screen, bad if you set min width, regardless of how small the screen size is, the element will never be smaller than that min-width. Can be bigger,but never smaller.
Just like the max -width works.

Comment: There is something else going on, it has to do with how 'flex' is managing the space in the layout.  This approach highlights a subtlety that I have not seen before (I don't use flex all that much). Good question! (I will take another look at this later and I come up with an explanation, I will post it.)

Comment: Yeps, bacause you dont set any width on `icon` and `<p>` so its will auto width them self (depends on content/text). This is so many ways to fix this problem (like.. set width both `icon` and `<p>` or use `!important` for width bla bla) But I would recomment to re-layout if screen is less as mobile devices (example 100% width on every cols if screen is less than 700px )

Comment: + You are using many duplicate properties `@extend .footer-font-awesome;` , Better if you read this how to use font icons http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Comment: Will have a looik for sure